# Inserting text from form to the popup. HTML/Jquery

Tags: jquery, forms

I have an easy problem for you :)

I need to make a short form with only one field for name. Lower should be a button which after clicking will show a popup with text: Hello (and here name from form). I just don't know how to connect this.

There's some code i already have:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>

    <div data-role="page">
      <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form method="post" action="demoform.asp">
          <label for="fname">Name:</label>
          <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname">
        </form>

        <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <a href="#myPopup" data-rel="popup" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-corner-all">Show Popup</a>

        <div data-role="popup" id="myPopup">
          <p>Hello ...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Please, help me... :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( "#fname" ).change(function() {
  $('#myPopup').html("<p>Hello "+$( "#fname" ).val()+"</p>");
});
```